# Values not Posted in the Database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to take attendance of a particular class and store the values in database.
I have used **INNER JOIN** to get the data from two tables and used those tables values in a form name attendance.

Now once i take attendance using the form i want to store that values in my database so i created another file name insertattendance.php.

The problem is it shows undefined index variables. ex.undefined index classid ..etc
so i tried using it in ***if(isset($_POST['submit'])*** There is no erros but the values are not posted.

My doubt is since iam using the values of my old tables is it showing error?.
Tell me how can i do this?

attendance.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>grade1</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="200" height="200">
<tr>
<th>classid</th>
<th>studentid</th>
<th>teacherid</th>
<th>locid</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>flag</th>
<th>comments</th>
</tr>
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$query = "(SELECT  a.classid, a.fname, b.teacherid, c.locid
           FROM class_master c JOIN student_master a 
           ON c.classid = a.classid JOIN teacher_link b
           ON c.classid = b.classid 
           WHERE c.classid = 'grade1' )";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
```

$i=1;

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<form action=insertattend.php method=POST>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input name=classid[$i] type=text value=" .$row['classid']." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input name=fname[$i] type=text value=" .$row['fname']." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input name=teacherid[$i] type=number value=" 
.$row['teacherid']." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=locid[$i] value=" .$row['locid']." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input name=date[$i] type=date value='date'></td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=radio id=attend name=attend[$i] value='present'>";?>P
<?php  echo "<input type=radio id=attend name=attend[$i] value='absent'>";?>A
<?php
echo"</td>";
echo "<td><input name=comment type=comment[$i] row=3 column=5></td>";
echo "</tr>";
 $i++;

}
 ?>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is my Insertattendance.php code

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
include 'conn.php';
$clnm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['classid']);

$stfn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);

$dt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);

$fg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['attend']);

$tid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['teacherid']);

$lid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['locid']);

$cmt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']); 

$inquery =("INSERT INTO attendance(classid, studentid, dateid, flag, teacherid, 
locid, comments) VALUES('$clnm', '$stfn', '$dt', '$fg', '$tid', '$lid', '$cmt')");
mysql_query($inquery, $dbconnection);


echo "<br>";
echo "values inserted successfully!!!!";
mysql_close($dbconnection);
};
?>
```

Comment: You need to use `isset` to check each of your `$_POST` values.

Comment: try to use mysql_error() to check if there are any query issue

Comment: where is name="submit" in submit button?

Comment: There is no input field in your html form

Comment: even giving name=submit no change

Answer (score 1):

Fix your `html` code:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>grade1</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="200" height="200">
    <tr>
        <th>classid</th>
        <th>studentid</th>
        <th>teacherid</th>
        <th>locid</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>flag</th>
        <th>comments</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    include 'conn.php';
    $query = "(SELECT  a.classid, a.fname, b.teacherid, c.locid
           FROM class_master c JOIN student_master a
           ON c.classid = a.classid JOIN teacher_link b
           ON c.classid = b.classid
           WHERE c.classid = 'grade1' )";
    $result = mysql_query($query);


    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<form action='insertattend.php' method='POST'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input name=classid type=text value=" .$row['classid']." ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input name=fname type=text value=" .$row['fname']." ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input name=teacherid type=number value=" .$row['teacherid']." ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=locid value=" .$row['locid']." ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input name=date type=date value='date'></td>";

        echo "<td>" . "<input type=radio id=attend name=attend value='present'>";?>P
        <?php echo "<input type=radio id=attend name=attend value='absent'>";?>A
        <?php
        echo"</td>";
        echo "<td><input name=comment type=comment row=3 column=5></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        //echo "</form>";
      ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
<?php } ?>
    <!--<form action="insertattend.php">-->
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will submit every single student data to form.

Comment: Nope i was not able to select attendance for all student

Answer (score 0):

These changes ought to be done on your **`attendance.php`** code

First move this `echo "<form action=insertattend.php method=POST>";` out of your `while`

Actually you are closing the **`<form>`** tag before the submit button.

```
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>"; //<--- Comment or Remove this line
```

Also, remove this line too (because you already defined above the while loop)

```
<form action="insertattend.php">  <!-- Remove this line -->
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Another thing is.. `echo "<td><input name=comment type=comment row=3 column=5></td>";` I don't think there is something called `type=comment` replace that to `type=text` or use a `<textarea>`

Comment: Hey Shankar! The OP's code is in really, and I mean really bad shape. I suggest you have a much closer look my brother ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You missed name="submit" in your attendance.php form.

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

use form opening and closing tags like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>grade1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="200" height="200">
            <tr>
                <th>classid</th>
                <th>studentid</th>
                <th>teacherid</th>
                <th>locid</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>flag</th>
                <th>comments</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            include 'conn.php';
            $query = "(SELECT  a.classid, a.fname, b.teacherid, c.locid
           FROM class_master c JOIN student_master a 
           ON c.classid = a.classid JOIN teacher_link b
           ON c.classid = b.classid 
           WHERE c.classid = 'grade1' )";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            ?>
            <form action=insertattend.php method=POST>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input name='classid[]' type=text value=" . $row['classid'] . " </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input name='fname[]' type=text value=" . $row['fname'] . " </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input name='teacherid[]' type=number value=" . $row['teacherid'] . " </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name='locid[]' value=" . $row['locid'] . " </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input name='date[]' type=date value='date'></td>";

                    echo "<td>" . "<input type=radio id=attend name='attend[]' value='present'>";
                    ?>P
                    <?php echo "<input type=radio id=attend name='attend[]' value='absent'>"; ?>A
                    <?php
                    echo"</td>";
                    echo "<td><input name='comment[]' type=comment row=3 column=5></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name= "submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You have to post the values as array in form fields inside the loop. Then you have to get the array of post values in *foreach* to insert all the records to the database.

Comment: only the last student value stored in database

Comment: @user3145732: use form name as array like this. name='classid[]'. then get the array values in submit page.

Answer (score 0):

```
There are two forms.      
Input types are in one form and submit button in another one.So avoid that and put together in one form.There is no need for another form with same action value. There are more than one student so write form outside while loop  and  then array name for input values. Then in php page values in array so use loop to get all values seperately.

<html>
<head>
<title>grade1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action=insertattend.php method=POST>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="200" height="200">
<tr>
<th>classid</th>
<th>studentid</th>
<th>teacherid</th>
<th>locid</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>flag</th>
<th>comments</th>
</tr>
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$query = "(SELECT  a.classid, a.fname, b.teacherid, c.locid
           FROM class_master c JOIN student_master a 
           ON c.classid = a.classid JOIN teacher_link b
           ON c.classid = b.classid 
           WHERE c.classid = 'grade1' )";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
$i=1;

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input name=classid[] type=text value=" .$row['classid']." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input name=fname[] type=text value=" .$row['fname']." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input name=teacherid[] type=number value=" 
.$row['teacherid']." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=locid[] value=" .$row['locid']." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input name=date[] type=date value='date'></td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=radio id=attend name=attend[] value='present'>";?>P
<?php  echo "<input type=radio id=attend name=attend[] value='absent'>";?>A
<?php
echo"</td>";
echo "<td><input name=comment[] type=text row=3 column=5></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
 ?>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And in php page you take size of any of the coming array
For eg:sizeof(classid);using that write for loop to accept values

Comment: For your code only the last student value is stored in database and the flag present or absent can be set only for one student.

Comment: so use form in while loop but give unique name for input values

Comment: There are more than one student. But no need for write form inside loop.Please give array name for text boxes.

Comment: id dono how to give it in array

Comment: just like name[] that is taken as array.Check my answer and then ask about that one.

Comment: sorry no change and was able to check only one student attendance radio box

Comment: Adars can u send some example links for that

Comment: i didn't get any link but i did it in my projets